# How to pass URL parameter from route to middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, middleware

If I have middleware like:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class SomeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $id = null)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In kernel.php:

```
'someMiddleware'    => \App\Http\Middleware\SomeMiddleware::class,
```

In routes.php :

```
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'someMiddleware']);
```

How I can pass id captured in {id} to my middleware?
I know that I can pass some custom parameter like this:

```
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'someMiddleware:16']);
```

But in laravel documentation there is no described how to pass argument captured in route pattern.

Comment: follow this docs for middleware parameter http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can get the parameter from inside the middleware like this:

```
//your middleware's method  
public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
{
    //get the ID
    $id = $request->id
}
```